# What is the best way to control a variable with radio buttons?

Tags: android, radio-button, material-design

I'm very new to Android programming, and I'm unable to find out what the accepted way to reach my goal is:

I have a variable in my main activity (`sortOrder`), which I want to set using radio buttons in a different activity. At the moment, I just change MainActivity.sortOrder from the other activity with a big switch case, so I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way.

Also, at the moment the radio buttons "forget" their choice when I return to MainActivity. Is is possible to save the selected radio button, and set the variable from that in MainActivity?

## Here's some  code:

in `MainActivity`:

```
public static String sortOrder;
public static int checkedId;
```

These are given values in `onCreate`:

```
sortOrder = ShipContract.ShipEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NAME + " ASC";
checkedId = R.id.sort_name;
```

And here is `OptionsSort`, which is started from `MainActivity`:

```
public class OptionsSort extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_options_sort);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    RadioButton checkedButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(MainActivity.checkedId);
    checkedButton.setChecked(true);
}

public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.sort_name:
            if (checked)
                MainActivity.sortOrder = ShipContract.ShipEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NAME + " ASC";
            break;
        case R.id.sort_date:
            if (checked)
                MainActivity.sortOrder = ShipContract.ShipEntry.COLUMN_NAME_DATE + " ASC";
            break;
        case R.id.sort_capacity:
            if (checked)
                MainActivity.sortOrder = ShipContract.ShipEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CAPACITY + " ASC";
            break;
        case R.id.sort_line:
            if (checked)
                MainActivity.sortOrder = ShipContract.ShipEntry.COLUMN_NAME_LINE + " ASC";
            break;
        case R.id.sort_displacement:
            if (checked)
                MainActivity.sortOrder = ShipContract.ShipEntry.COLUMN_NAME_DISPLACEMENT + " ASC";
            break;
        case R.id.sort_speed:
            if (checked)
                MainActivity.sortOrder = ShipContract.ShipEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SPEED + " ASC";
            break;
        case R.id.sort_power:
            if (checked)
                MainActivity.sortOrder = ShipContract.ShipEntry.COLUMN_NAME_POWER + " ASC";
            break;
    }
    RadioGroup radiogroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.sort_group);
    MainActivity.checkedId = radiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    finish();
}
```

}

Comment: Let's see if I understand your problem - you have 2 activities. And in the second on there is a logic which changes **sortOrder** and based one the value in **sortOrder** you want to change the state of a RadioButton, right?

Comment: Yes. What I've now done is saving the id of the selected RadioButton in MainActivity and using setChecked in the second activity's onCreate. But it still feels very hackish ..

Comment: Yep it is hackish (no offends) Can you please add your code to the question, so we can have a better look at it?

Comment: @MadTux you have to store your `RadioButton` selection in `SharedPreference` so that in other `Activity` if you won't to set it then you could.

Comment: @Ironman thanks, I'll have a look at that ..

Answer (score 0):

so far i understand your problem you want to take sortOder value from activity B and bring it to Activity A.This can be achieved if you startActivityForResult and there in activity B when you are done with everything just call setresult method and give it the resultant intent and finish this activity B.
In activity A you have to override onActivityResult and handle the result from activity B .

like 
startActivityForResult(new Intent(this,ActivityB.class),123);

@Override

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intentdata) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

```
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

if (requestCode==123)
    {
      String sordData= data.getStringExtra("sortOrder","byName")
            sortYourDAta(sordData);
    }
}
```

}

and in activity b when sort order is selected

just store value in a variable sortOrder="byDate";

and onbackpressed or when ever you want to go back just call this
setResult(123,new Intent().putExtra("sortOrder",sortOrder));
finish();